# rest assured post serialization json body

Tags: json, swagger, deserialization, rest-assured

how can i use data as it is stated in swagger? as i understand now i can use without **[]**. how can i add it?

```
public static JSONObject assignmentList(String rolename) {
            JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
            requestParams.put("origin", "LOCAL");
            requestParams.put("roleID", roleId);
            requestParams.put("roleName", rolename);
            requestParams.put("userOrGroupID", userId);
            return requestParams;
        }
```

**rest assured method is:**

```
public static void addAssignment(String rolename) {
            JSONObject assignmentBody = assignmentList(rolename);
            localLogin.localLogin("superadmin","Smoke.1234");

  res = given()
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + localLogin.accessToken)
            .header("Content-type", "application/json")
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .accept(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(assignmentBody)
            .when()
            .post("https://localhost:8090/api/v1/user-role-assignments")
            .then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).log().all().statusCode(201).extract().response();
```

**error when execute;**

```
"error": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList...........` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<............tDTO>` out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]",
```

**Swagger dto usage example**

dtoList

```
[
  {
    "origin": "string",
    "roleID": "string",
    "roleName": "string",
    "userOrGroupID": "string"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `JSONObject` in a List.

```
.body(assignmentBody)
```

-->

```
.body(Arrays.asList(assignmentBody))
```